# vbscript to dynamically update the excel cell range,when source data is updated and refresh the pivot table simultaneously

Tags: vbscript, rstudio

I have an excel workbook consisting of a source data and a pivot table.
the source data gets updated with new records daily along with some changes in the existing data.

I have written a vbscript in notepad and saved it with .vbs and I am calling it from Rstudio to perform the refresh pivot table action.

But,when I run this script in Rstuido :

```
  pathofvbscript = ("D:\\Users\\703225799\\WIP\\R\\pivot\\r5.vbs")
  shell(shQuote(normalizePath(pathofvbscript)),"cscript",flag = 
  "//nologo")
```

I am getting the following error :

```
   D:\Users\703225799\WIP\R\pivot\r5.vbs(14, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime 
   error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objWB.Range'
```

VBS code :

```
 '------------------------------------------------------------------------
 'Set Pivot Table & Source Worksheet
 '------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Set objExcel    = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWB       = 
  objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\703225799\WIP\R\pivot\New 
  folder\Book1.xlsx")
  Set Pivot_Sheet = objWB.Worksheets("pvt")

  '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  'Enter in Pivot Table Name
  '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   PivotName = "PivotTable1"
   objWB.Activate

   Set StartPoint = objWB.Range("A1")
   LastCol = StartPoint.End(xlToRight).Column
   DownCell = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
   Set DataRange = Data_Sheet.Range(StartPoint, Cells(DownCell, LastCol))

   New_range = objWB.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(xlR1C1)

   Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName). _
   ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
   PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,NewRange)

   '----------------------------------------------------------------------
   'Ensure Pivot Table is Refreshed
   '----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Pivot_Sheet.PivotTables(PivotName).RefreshTable

   'Data_Sheet.Save
   'MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now saved."

   'Data_Sheet.Close
   'MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now closed."

   'objExcel.Quit
   'MsgBox "objExcel quit."

   '----------------------------------------------------------------------
   'Complete Message
   '----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Pivot_Sheet.Activate
    MsgBox "Your Pivot Table is now updated."


    objWB.Save
    objWB.Close 

    set objExcel   = Nothing
    set Data_Sheet = Nothing
    Set Pivot_Sheet = Nothing
```

Please help with the error.

Thanks,
Sayan

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `Pivot_Sheet.Range("A1")` instead of `objWB.Range("A1")` as the worksheet object is Pivot_sheet

Comment: Workbook Object won't support 'Range' property that's why you are getting the exception

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be `Data_Sheet.Range` in this case.